# shockwave doesnt work!

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome, chromium and firefox dont run shockwave flash, I don't know what else I should do to solve this problem, this is pissing me off.

I've tried every 'possible' solution from the forums or blogs but no one works yet. Every blog or post or forum say that you need to delete pepperflash.so or something like that to get it working,

But the problem is...  I don't have any pepperflash.so either!!!. So, I dont find the way to solve this problem. Does anyone know any way?

Comment: Behave yourself. The swearing is removed but please do not do that again. And we expect you to include what you tried and what failed to work.

Comment: What is your hardware configuration? Are you sure that is supported by Flash?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, this is a 32bit system, but it should work! I don't know if I should uninstall flash and install it again or what

Comment: Firefox can't use Pepper Flash, so you should have the standard Flash installed for that.

Answer (score 0):

try updating the system by:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and also check the updates for the browsers you are currently using...